# Backup with Compression of large TDE databases

Tags: sql-server-2016, backup, compression, transparent-data-encryption

I'm looking for help with Backup Compression for TDE databases, I'm working out of SQL 2016 (SP3-CU1) and am aware that the MaxTransferSize must be specified as over 64K. A few these DBs are over 600gb and most are over 200gb, however all of the examples I've found in MS documents/blogs and other SQL support sites all use examples with much smaller files.

With these smaller files they are able to compress the backup down to less than half the original, some are a quarter of the original.  However my test are only creating files around 25 to 30% smaller than the original and we really need to get them down a good bit smaller.

There are many reasons why, but ultimately we're hoping to greatly decrease the size of the files to increase the speed of file transfer.

Can anyone tell me if what we are seeing is because of the file size of the DBs we're trying to backup, or is there possibly some other parameter that I should be using/setting that is necessary to accommodate these large DBs?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [BigDatabase] 
TO DISK = 'K:\ForTest\BigDbBkupWCompression.bak'
WITH NOFORMAT,
    NOINIT,
    NAME = 'BigDatabase-Full Database Backup', 
    SKIP, 
    NOREWIND, 
    NOUNLOAD, 
    COMPRESSION,  
    STATS = 10,
    MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 131072
GO
'''
```

Comment: Compression ratio depends on the file contents rather than size (for non-trivial sizes; if the file size is comparable with the compression dictionary size, the ratio can get negative). The more random the data, the worse the compression ratio.

Comment: What's the root issue you are trying to resolve? Backup takes too long? Backup overwhelms the storage and other things slows down? Something else?

Comment: Have you tried striping your backups to multiple files?  I find that many smaller files transfer faster than a single large file.  That may be another way to attack that issue.  Your command syntax looks good and the settings are good, so as @mustaccio says, it's probably the contents of your database rather than anything else.

Comment: have you read this?
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/backup-compression-for-tde-enabled-databases-important-fixes-in/ba-p/385593

Comment: @vonPryz  so sorry I didn't see these additional comments!  We are migrating from "on prim" SQL to SQL Managed Instances (MIs), however our source "host environment" does not allow for the connectivity required to use Microsoft's various migration tools, so we're having to azCopy backup files thru the one "hole" they were willing to poke open for us, then we perform "restores" to get our data into the new MIs... ...

Comment: @vonPryz  ... ... To add to the difficulty, with little previous DB management, the DBs have been allowed to grow quite large with many over 500GB, and of course the larger the file the longer the transfer takes.  We will implement our migration in multiple stages hoping to have as little downtime as possible for each "customer".  I was hoping to leverage the compressed backups so we'd have smaller files to transfer and ultimately shorten the downtime for each stage.